# jquery ajax returns same value for every result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a this form:

```
<script src="js/results.js"></script>
    <div class="container" id="results">
    <form action="inc/roll.php" method="POST" id="game">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col m2">
             <p>
                <label>
                <input name="bet" type="radio" value="1000" id="bet" checked/>
                <span>1000</span>
                </label>
             </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col m2">
             <p>
                <label>
                <input name="bet" type="radio" value="10000" id="bet"  />
                <span>10,000</span>
                </label>
             </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col m2">
             <p>
                <label>
                <input name="bet" type="radio" value="100000" id="bet"  />
                <span>100,000</span>
                </label>
             </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col m2">
             <p>
                <label>
                <input name="bet" type="radio" value="1000000" id="bet" />
                <span>1,000,000</span>
                </label>
             </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col m2">
             <p>
                <label>
                <input name="choice" type="radio" value="1" id="choice" checked/>
                <span>1</span>
                </label>
             </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col m2">
             <p>
                <label>
                <input name="choice" type="radio" value="2" id="choice"  />
                <span>2</span>
                </label>
             </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col m2">
             <p>
                <label>
                <input name="choice" type="radio" value="3" id="choice"  />
                <span>3</span>
                </label>
             </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col m2">
             <p>
                <label>
                <input name="choice" type="radio" value="4" id="choice" />
                <span>4</span>
                </label>
             </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col m2">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Play!">
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

You select 2 values, your "bet" and the number you think is going to be the winner (1,2,3 or 4). The form is submitted to this PHP script (roll.php):

```
<?php

require_once('errors.php');

$choice = $_POST['choice'];
$bet    = $_POST['bet'];

if (!empty($choice) && !empty($bet)) {

function roll_dice() {
$roll_min = 1000;
$roll_max = 100000;
$roll = random_int($roll_min, $roll_max);

return ($roll % 4);
  }

  for ($x = 0; $x <= 1000; $x++) {

    $results = roll_dice();

   if ($results == 0) {
  roll_dice();
  }
if ($results != 0) {
    
    if ($choice == $results) {
        $status = array(
            "status"    => "winner",
            "choice"    => $choice,
            "results"   => $results,
            "bet"       => $bet,
            "prize"     => $bet * 2.5
        );
        echo json_encode($status);
        exit;
      }
      else {
        $status = array(
            "status"    => "loser",
            "choice"    => $choice,
            "results"   => $results,
            "bet"       => $bet,
            "prize" => 0
        );

        echo json_encode($status);
        exit;
    }


    }
  }
}
```

the PHP scripts results are parsed by this ajax function (results.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("form").submit(function (event) {
var formData = {
  choice: $("#choice").val(),
  bet: $("#bet").val() 
};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "inc/roll.php",
  data: formData,
  dataType: "json",
  encode: true,
}).done(function (data) {
  if (data["status"] == "winner") {
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Status: " + data["status"] + "<br />Results: " + data["results"] + "<br />Choice: " + data["choice"] + "<br />Bet: " + data["bet"] + "<br />You won: " + data["prize"];
  }
  if (data["status"] == "loser") {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Status: " + data["status"] + "<br />Results: " + data["results"] + "<br />Choice: " + data["choice"] + "<br />You lost: " + data["bet"];
  }

});

event.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

The problem is that the ajax always returns the results as:

```
Status: winner/loser
Results: 2 
Choice: 1 <-- this is always 1 no matter what you select in the form 
You lost/won: 1000 <-- this is always 1000 no matter what you select in the form
```

If you comment out the results.js from the html (making it non-ajax) the PHP script on its own returns the correct results.

I would like some help understanding why the ajax function is not returning the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the `id` as *choice* and *bet*. You are using `$("#choice").val()` and `$("#bet").val()` to get these values, but since you have multiple elements with the same id, jQuery is only selecting the first one it encounters with that *id*. That's why you're always getting a choice of 1 and a bet of 1000.

You should use the unique *id* attribute of the elements.

To fix this issue, you can use *name* attribute along with `checked` property like the following way:

```
....
var formData = {
  choice: $("input[name='choice']:checked").val(),
  bet: $("input[name='bet']:checked").val()
};
....
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, however that doesnt seem to be working, Im still getting the same results.

Comment: @jon, I will suggest you to debug your code so that you can find out from which point the issue is arising.

Comment: i eventually figure it out and got it working. thanks for you help.

Comment: @jon, that's really great. I will suggest you to post the solution for the future reader of the post.